# Cuda: Finding out if pointer is a device or host pointer

Tags: cuda

E.g. CUBLAS contains functions that accept device or host pointers as arguments (for example the alpha and beta arguments to cublas<t>gemm(), see [1]). How do I write a function with this kind of functionality? What are the limitations? What about corner cases like devices with unified address space?

Example source code that does this the right way would be awesome.

[1] http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_8_1

Comment: If you are willing to do all host allocations using a cuda runtime API call (such as [cudaHostAlloc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c)), then you might be interested in [this API call](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED) to do pointer introspection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic pointer introspection in CUBLAS. The library uses an explicit, per context switch which controls how pointers are interpreted (see [`cudaSetPointerMode`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_5_6)).